# Loading 532 columns from a CSV file into a DB2 table

Tags: database, csv, import, db2

Summary : **Is there a limit to the number of columns which can be Imported/Loaded from a CSV file? If yes, what is the workaround? Thanks**

I am very new to DB2, and I am supposed to import a | (pipe) delimited csv file which contains 532 columns into a DB2 table which also has 532 columns in exact positions as the csv. I also have a smaller file with only 27 columns in both csv and table. I am using the following command:

```
IMPORT FROM "C:\myfile.csv" OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL| METHOD P (1, 2,....27) MESSAGES "C:\messages.txt" INSERT INTO PRE_SUBS_GPRS2_1010 (col1,col2,....col27);
```

This works fine.

But in the second file, which is like:

```
IMPORT FROM "C:\myfile.csv" OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL| METHOD P (1, 2,....532) MESSAGES "C:\messages.txt" INSERT INTO PRE_SUBS_GPRS_1010 (col1,col2,....col532);
```

It does not work. It gives me an error that says:

```
SQL3037N  An SQL error "-206" occurred during Import processing.

Explanation: 

An SQL error occurred during processing of the Action String (for 
example, "REPLACE into ...") parameter.  

 The command cannot be processed.  

User Response: 

 Look at the SQLCODE (message number) in the message for more 
information.  Make changes and resubmit the command.
```

I am using the Control Center to run the query, not command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because one of the column names in the list of columns of the INSERT statement was more than 30 characters long. It was getting truncated and was not recognized.

Hope this helps others in future. Please let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error code is SQL0206 and the documentation about this error is here
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00206n.html

For the limits, I think the maximal quantity of columns in an import should be the maximal quantity permitted for a Table. Take a look in the information center 
Database fundamentals > SQL > SQL and XML limits 
Maximum number of columns in a table 7  1012

Try to import just one row. If you have problems, probably is due to incompatibility of types, column order, duplicated rows with the already present in the table.